# Validating each property before returning object

Tags: ios, objective-c, github-mantle

While using [Mantle](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle), is there a possibility to before returning the object we are creating (on this case via JSON) to verify that X and Y properties are not nil?

Imagine this class:

```
@interface Person : MTLModel <MTLJSONSerializing>

@property(nonatomic,strong,readonly)NSString *name;
@property(nonatomic,strong,readonly)NSString *age;

@end
```

I want a way to verify that if the JSON I received doesn't have the `name` (for some reason there was an issue on server's DB) I will return a `nil` Person, as it doesn't make sense to create that object without that property set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `MTLJSONSerializing` protocol method [`classForParsingJSONDictionary:`](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle/blob/c6a4f0b06ca6c46f0275abaa86973e3f96faa8ef/Mantle/MTLJSONAdapter.h#L53) to return nil rather than an invalid object:

```
// In your MTLModelSubclass.m
//
+ (Class)classForParsingJSONDictionary:(NSDictionary *)JSONDictionary {
    if (JSONDictionary[@"name"] == nil || JSONDictionary[@"age"] == nil) {
        return nil;
    }
    return self.class;
}
```

Comment: Only downside is that this requires you to hardcode the keys in two places and it doesnt allow you to pass back errors to the system unlike `initWithDictionary:error:` or `validate:`

Comment: Oh, this is not real solution, this is just a hack. Take a look at `validate:` method instead and override it.

Answer (score 4):

Whilst you could override the initialiser. It seems more concise to override the `validate:` as this is called at the last stage before `Mantle` returns the deserialised object. Makes sense to put all your validation logic in a `validate` method...

See the final line of the `MTLJSONAdapter`

```
id model = [self.modelClass modelWithDictionary:dictionaryValue error:error];
return [model validate:error] ? model : nil;
```

This tells us that if our custom model returns `NO` from `validate`, then Mantle will discard the object.

So you could in your subclass simply perform the following:

```
- (BOOL)validate:(NSError **)error {
    return [super validate:error] && self.name.length > 0; 
}
```

Ideally in your own implementation you probably want to return an appropriate error.

The validate method will then call Foundation's `validateValue:forKey:error:` for every property that you registered with Mantle in `JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey`. So if you want a more controlled validation setup you could also validate your data here..

Answer (score 0):

In fact I don't use Mantle, but for validation I use another GitHub Library called [RPJSONValidator](https://github.com/reygonzales/RPJSONValidator)

It tells you the type that you expect and what type the value has been arrived.

A simple example code

```
NSError *error;

[RPJSONValidator validateValuesFrom:json
                   withRequirements:@{
                           @"phoneNumber" : [RPValidatorPredicate.isString lengthIsGreaterThanOrEqualTo:@7],
                           @"name" : RPValidatorPredicate.isString,
                           @"age" : RPValidatorPredicate.isNumber.isOptional,
                           @"weight" : RPValidatorPredicate.isString,
                           @"ssn" : RPValidatorPredicate.isNull,
                           @"height" : RPValidatorPredicate.isString,
                           @"children" : RPValidatorPredicate.isArray,
                           @"parents" : [RPValidatorPredicate.isArray lengthIsGreaterThan:@1]
                   } error:&error];

if(error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [RPJSONValidator prettyStringGivenRPJSONValidatorError:error]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Woohoo, no errors!");
}
```

Each key-value pair describes requirements for each JSON value. For example, the key-value pair `@"name"` : `RPValidatorPredicate.isString` will place a requirement on the JSON value with key "name" to be an `NSString`. We can also chain requirements. For example, `@"age"` : `RPValidatorPredicate.isNumber.isOptional` will place a requirement on the value of "age" to be an `NSNumber`, but only if it exists in the JSON.

Comment: I don't want to add more dependencies to the project, Erid.

Comment: It's ok, I thought I could give you an example but it's ok. :)

Answer (score 0):

I use a very old version of Mantle.  YMMV

You can override  the *[MTLModel modelWithExternalRepresentation]* selector.  Make sure to call *[super modelWithExternalRepresentation]* and then add your own code to check for validate data.

Answer (score 0):

I followed a small [issue](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle/issues/141) opened on Mantle:

```
- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionaryValue error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
{
    BOOL isValid = NO;
    if (self = [super initWithDictionary:dictionaryValue error:error])
    {
        isValid = ...
    }

    return isValid?self:nil;
}
```

So in the end just override:

```
- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionaryValue error:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error
```

Comment: This will prevent you from ever creating a model with a nil age or name (even manually, not just from JSON.) If you only want to prevent this when creating a model from JSON, my answer is more correct.

Comment: @DavidCaunt this object only makes sense from JSON, not manually.

Comment: Then you could prefer my method for not doing all of the Mantle work - it will return nil before mapping the data to property keys, performing transformations etc

Comment: @DavidCaunt yes, I will go with your approach as it's more "natural" than mine.